How do I find sales data for my book?
My book is currently for sale online. The last sales data report from Amazon covered only through June, a date earlier than we started to sell (July 31, 2024 would be the earliest sale date based upon what little we know).  We have been promised a full report by the second week of November, but frankly have a lot of ants in our pants and are having a hard time trying to decipher the web of silence surrounding us in sales. The book is being offered in the US, Canada, eight European countries, and Australia. Do you have any suggestions to relieve the 'constant itch' of uncertainty?

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about writing at all, it is about sales information of an already published book. I think it is just trying to advertise the book.

Well, Amadeus, to be clear, the question evolved as we get more queasy about what may be going on, and reflecting upon the feeling, I was hoping new authors (such as us) have had similar experiences with their virgin offerings.  No sales pitch here at all.  I joined as I looked at this portal as an aide to guide our efforts through some iceberg-laden waters.  If there is a voice out there who has felt the same way, what an interesting discussion it would be, and hopefully would help quell a lot of angst out there, that I am aware exists.  Sorry you do not feel the same way!

Welcome to Writing.SE! I've removed the information about your book, as it's not strictly necessary and was attracting the wrong sort of attention. We already have a couple of questions about how to identify a book's sales figures, so I'll also be closing this as a duplicate of those. Hopefully the answers to those questions are helpful to you.

Re: "Do you have any suggestions to relieve the 'constant itch' of uncertainty?" It is common that publishers report sales data (and pay royalties) only once or twice a year. It is your job as a professional author to put that question out of your mind and write the next book. Dealing with uncertainty is part of adult life.
